# How to stop duplicate entry into django model

Tags: django-forms

I want to stop duplicate entry into form field. If I enter the same data which is already stored into database then it shows an error message or it won't stored. Please Help me guys. I am new in Django.

## Form.html File

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'manager_add' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
              <fieldset>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Manager Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                       <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="mname" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select Department</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                       <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                          <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="dprtmnt">
                             <option>Department 1</option>
                             <option>Department 2</option>
                             <option>Department 3</option>
                             <option>Department 4</option>
                          </select>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                       <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                       <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input id="phoneNumber" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <button>Submit</button>
              </fieldset>
           </form>
```

## Model.py File

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dprtmnt = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mname
```

## View.py File

```
def manager_add(request):
    print("Form is submitted successfully!")
    mname = request.POST.get("mname", False)
    dprtmnt = request.POST.get("dprtmnt", False)
    email = request.POST.get("email", False)
    phone = request.POST.get("phone", False)

    ManagerAdd = Manager(mname = mname, dprtmnt = dprtmnt, email = email, phone = phone, is_active=False) 
    ManagerAdd.save()

    return render(request,'manageradd.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Manager.objects.get_or_create()`, see [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) of the doc.

You can also simple check if an entry already exists in your database:

```
try:
    Manager.objects.get(mname = mname, dprtmnt = dprtmnt, email = email, phone = phone)
    # Do things if manager exists
except:
    # Create your new manager
```

Comment: Yes It's Working. @Cyrlop